# ContactForm7 - Check if Checkbox is Checked

Tags: jquery, wordpress, checkbox

I'm stuck on how to check whether or not a checkbox has been selected using jQuery. Basically, if the checkbox is checked then I need it to run a function.

In the WordPress post, I only have to use the shortcode which is using this id:

```
 [contact-form-7 id="78" title="BusinessForm"]
```

however, it is ouputting this as the HTML:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap sameAddress">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox sameAddress" id="sameAddress">
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sameAddress[]" value="Yes">
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Yes</span>
        </span>
    </span>
 </span>
```

and here is the jQuery that I am using:

```
$(input[value='sameAddress[]']).change(function() {

    var alreadyChecked = $(this).hasClass('alreadyChecked');

    if (alreadyChecked) {
        alert('This does not have the class');  
        $(this).addClass('alreadyChecked');
    } else {
        alert('This has the class, yay!!!!! ');
    }

});
```

Can someone help me refine this and make it run a function/alert when the checkbox is selected? Thanks in advance.

**edit:** Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uk3E3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you binding the event was wrong, Use the attribute selector like this,

```
$("input[name = 'sameAddress[]']").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        alert("checked");
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uk3E3/2/)

In your code, there is no check box with value `sameAddress[]`. So it wont bind change events to any of the checkboxes.

`this.checked` will return true, if the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below Jquery function it will help you to reach solution

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    alert("test");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for half a day how can I use the contactform7 hiding a div - but not with select element but - with checkbox... - and the checkbox is not modified on checking, just on clicking. The checkbox value is not modified... I found this solution working (thanks to all the stackoverflow user)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Hide the field initially
    $("#hide1").hide(); 

    //Show the text field only when the third option is chosen - this doesn't
    $("input[name = 'programs-select1[]']").change(function () {
    if (this.checked)  {
                    $("#hide1").show();
            }
            else {
                    $("#hide1").hide();
            }
    });

});
```

The contact form 7 is looking like:

```
[checkbox programs-select1 id:programs-select1 use_label_element "Week 1"]
<div id="hide1" class="hide">
[select* fullhalfboard-select1 id:fullhalfboard-select1 use_label_element "element1" "element2" "element3"]
</div>
```